# get File Path using input type ='File' in Angular 7 giving fake path

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 and input type 'File' using below code but it gives FakePath:

```
 <input class="form-control" (change)="handleUpload($event)" placeholder="File Name" autocomplete="off" type="file" readonly
                    autofocus />

 public handleUpload(e) {
this.filePath = e.target.value; }


 handleUpload1(event: any) {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
    this.filePath = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}   }
```

I have also done Internet Setting ""Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" but still not working.

Comment: you can't get path of your local system there is a reason for security else all websites can snoop in your machine

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Is there any other way to read full file path? In my case, I wan to read full path and save that path in database.

Comment: If you put a client executable like a JAR or Flash you can else there is no way of knowing. You can do it in your browser by lowering browser security (so all attackers can attack you) but when you deploy and run in someone else machine it will not work

Comment: on second thought why do you need the file path what's your intent maybe I can help with an alternative solution

Comment: I want to read excel file and display data in angular grid. So I am sending file path from UI to API and from API side I read file data and response to UI.